# ¿Como modificar un archivo .txt desde c++?

Tags: c++, archivo

Quiero modificar un archivo `.txt` desde un programa desarrollado en `c++`, ya tengo un código desarrollado que crea el archivo y también lo lee, pero no lo modifica y no encuentro como realizarlo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void presentaMenuGeneral() {
  string contenido;
  int opcion;
do {
system("cls");
    cout << "[:]Menu principal\n" << endl;
    cout << "[1]Crear archivo de texto" << endl;
    cout << "[2]Abrir archivo de texto" << endl;
    cout << "[3]Modificar archivo de texto" << endl;
    cout << "[0]Salir del programa\n" << endl;
    cout << "Ingresa la opcion: ";
    cin >> opcion;
    switch (opcion) {
    case 0:
        break;
case 1:{
  cout << "Ingresa el contenido del archivo: ";
  cin.ignore();
  getline(cin, contenido);
  ofstream fs("nombre.txt");
  fs << contenido << endl;
  fs.close();
  cout << "El archivo ha sido creado correctamente" << endl;
  system("pause");
  break;
}
case 2:{
  ifstream fs("nombre.txt", ios::in);
  char linea[128];
  long contador = 0L;
  if(fs.fail())
  cerr << "El fichero no existe" << endl;
  else
  while(!fs.eof())
  {
      fs.getline(linea, sizeof(linea));
      cout << linea << endl;
      if((++contador % 24)==0)
      {
          cout << "continuar...";
          cin.get();
      }
  }
  fs.close();
  system("pause");
  break;
}
case 3:
        break;
default:
        cout << "\nEl numero de opcion escrito no es valido\n" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
  } while (opcion != 0);
}

int main(){
 presentaMenuGeneral();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola Eduardo, ¿podrías agregar el código para modificar el archivo? Tengo la impresión que de ese no has agregado nada y es con el que tienes problemas precisamente.

Comment: @toledano de hecho no agregue nada en el case 3 porque no se como realizarlo es por el motivo que lo publique el código en mi pregunta, ya que no tengo idea de como modificar el contenido del archivo .txt , o no se a que te refieras con no agregado nada.

Comment: Comprendo. Recuerda que Stackoverflow en español no funciona con opiniones ni con recomendaciones, porque seguramente eso es lo que estás buscando. Te recomiendo que investigues en Google como modificar archivos de texto y si tienes algún problema específico con el código, entonces lo publiques agregando, ahora si, un [_ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable_](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Claro conozco como trabaja Stackoverflow y me han ayudado bastante respondiendo algunas preguntas, y vaya que hay preguntas bastantes complicada para mi que me han resulto y no estoy pidiendo opiniones, hay personas que me han proporcionado código para algunos problemas que eh tenido. Solo estoy planteando la pregunta para saber como es que se trabaja la modificación de archivos ya que no lo eh encontrado en google, eh visto algunas paginas pero no es lo que busco realmente. De igual forma si no hay alguien que me pueda ayudar me lo tengo que ingeniar y si es posible publico la respuesta aquí.

Comment: Podés guardar las líneas de texto en un array o vector de string, luego en la opción 2 mostrás por pantalla ese array con las líneas numeradas, entonces el usuario puede elegir, como lo hace con el menú, qué línea modifica. Con ese método también se podría implementar la opción ***Deshacer***. Posiblemente un menú horizontal, además del vertical que ya tiene tu programa, ayudaría para las opciones de edición. No te paso código porque aún no tengo instalado un compilador de C/C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay 2 formas de modificar un archivo:

1. Cargar todo el contenido en memoria, modificar lo que quieras, y luego escribir en el archivo.
2. Crear un archivo temporal, ir escribiendo en ese archivo, y al final reemplazar el original por el temporal.

Veamos la segunda opción (con un archivo temporal), que tiene menores chances de fallar.

```cpp
case 3:{
  string buscar;      // texto a buscar
  string reemplazar;  // reemplazar por

  //ingresa textos
  cout << "Ingresa el texto a buscar: ";
  cin.ignore();
  getline(cin, buscar);
  cout << "Ingresa el texto para reemplazarlo: ";
  cin.ignore();
  getline(cin, reemplazar);


  ifstream fs("nombre.txt"); //leer de este archivo
  ofstream fstemp("nombretemp.txt"); //escribir en este archivo
  if(!fs || !fstemp) //no se pudo abrir alguno de los 2
  {
    cout << "Error al abrir el archivo!" << endl;
    break;
  }

  //modificar linea a linea
  while(fs >> contenido)
  {
    if(contenido == buscar){  //se encontro
      contenido = reemplazar; //reemplazar
    }
    fstemp << contenido << endl;
  }

  //reemplazar un archivo por otro
  fs.close();
  fstemp.close();
  remove("nombre.txt");                    // borrar el original
  rename("nombretemp.txt", "nombre.txt");  // renombrar el temporal

  //siguiendo la logica que usaste en el resto
  cout << "El archivo ha sido modificado correctamente" << endl;
  system("pause");
  break;
}
```