# Error de compilación con C++

Tags: compilacion

Acabo de empezar hoy a programar un "Videojuego" (Es un programa que ejecuta una ventana de terminal para poder introducir y recibir texto) y tengo un problema con las funciones, muchas de las cosas que estoy usando aquí las aprendí hoy en blogs de distintas plataformas, lo cual ha ocasionado que no esté seguro de cuál es el error o el causante de este.

La intención de esta pregunta es ver si alguien podría aclararme o ayudarme un poco a solucionar el error de compilación de mi programa.

Edit: Este es el mensaje de terminal al intentar correr el programa:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘void menu_jugar()’:
prog.cpp:91:5: error: ‘menu_principal’ was not declared in this scope
     menu_principal();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```cpp
/*
╭━━━╮╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭╮╱╱╱╱╭━━━╮
┃╭━╮┃╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭╯╰╮╱╱╱┃╭━╮┃
┃╰━╯┣━┳━━┳╮╱╭┳━━┳━┻╮╭╋━━╮╰╯╭╯┃
┃╭━━┫╭┫╭╮┃┃╱┃┃┃━┫╭━┫┃┃╭╮┃╭╮╰╮┃
┃┃╱╱┃┃┃╰╯┃╰━╯┃┃━┫╰━┫╰┫╰╯┃┃╰━╯┃
╰╯╱╱╰╯╰━━┻━╮╭┻━━┻━━┻━┻━━╯╰━━━╯
╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭━╯┃
╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╰━━╯


█▀█ █▀█ █▀█   ▄▀█ █░░ █▀▀ ▀▄▀ █▀█ ▀▄▀ █▀█
█▀▀ █▄█ █▀▄   █▀█ █▄▄ ██▄ █░█ █▄█ █░█ █▄█
*/

// #pragma GCC optimize("Ofast,no-stack-protector,unroll-loops,fast-math")
// #pragma GCC target("avx,avx2,fma")
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#define f first
#define s second
#define fore(i,a,b) for(int i = (a), ThxMK = (b); i < ThxMK; ++i)
#define pb push_back
#define all(s) begin(s), end(s)
#define _ ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
#define sz(s) int(s.size())
#define ENDL '\n'
using namespace std;
typedef long double ld;
typedef long long lli;
typedef pair<lli,lli> ii;
typedef vector<lli> vi;
#define deb(x) cout << #x": " << (x) << endl;

vector <string> progreso;

void clear_screen (void)
{
    printf("%c[2J", (char)27);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void clear_line (void)
{
    printf("%c[2K", (char)27);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void cargar_partida(char n){
    string x = "guardado";
    x.pb('x');
    x.pb('.');
    x.pb('t');
    x.pb('x');
    x.pb('t');
    ifstream archivo("guardado1.txt");
    string s;
    while (getline(archivo, s)){
        progreso.pb(s);
    }
    return;
}

void menu_jugar(){
  clear_screen();
  cout << "░░█ █░█ █▀▀ ▄▀█ █▀█" << ENDL << "█▄█ █▄█ █▄█ █▀█ █▀▄" << ENDL << ENDL;
    cout << "[1] Archivo de Guardado 1" << ENDL << "[2] Archivo de Guardado 2" << ENDL << "[3] Archivo de Guardado 3" << ENDL << "[4] Volver" << ENDL;
    lli seleccionado;
    do{
        cout << ENDL << "Escribe el índice de alguna de las opciones para continuar: ";
        cin >> seleccionado;
        switch (seleccionado) {
            case 1:
                cargar_partida('1');
                break;

            case 2:
                cargar_partida('1');
                break;

            case 3:
                cargar_partida('1');
                break;

            case 4:
                menu_principal();
                break;

            default:
                cout << "índice u opción inválido." << ENDL;
                break;
        }
    } while (seleccionado != 4);
  // ifstream archivo("guardado1.txt");
  return;
}

void menu_principal(){
  clear_screen();
  cout << "╭━╮╭━╮╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭━━━╮╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭╮" << ENDL << "┃┃╰╯┃┃╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱┃╭━╮┃╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱┃┃" << ENDL << "┃╭╮╭╮┣━━┳━╮╭╮╭╮┃╰━╯┣━┳┳━╮╭━━┳┳━━┳━━┫┃" << ENDL << "┃┃┃┃┃┃┃━┫╭╮┫┃┃┃┃╭━━┫╭╋┫╭╮┫╭━╋┫╭╮┃╭╮┃┃" << ENDL << "┃┃┃┃┃┃┃━┫┃┃┃╰╯┃┃┃╱╱┃┃┃┃┃┃┃╰━┫┃╰╯┃╭╮┃╰╮" << ENDL << "╰╯╰╯╰┻━━┻╯╰┻━━╯╰╯╱╱╰╯╰┻╯╰┻━━┻┫╭━┻╯╰┻━╯" << ENDL << "╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱┃┃" << ENDL << "╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╰╯" << ENDL << ENDL;
  cout << "[1] Jugar" << ENDL << "[2] Opciones" << ENDL << "[3] Ayuda" << ENDL << "[4] Información" << ENDL << "[5] Salir" << ENDL;
  lli seleccionado;
  do{
    cout << ENDL << "Escribe el índice de alguna de las opciones para continuar: ";
    cin >> seleccionado;
    switch (seleccionado) {
      case 1:
        menu_jugar();
        break;

      case 2:
        break;

      case 3:
        break;

      case 4:
        break;

      case 5:
        clear_screen();
        cout << "╭━━━╮╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭╮╱╱╱╱╭━━━╮" << ENDL << "┃╭━╮┃╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭╯╰╮╱╱╱┃╭━╮┃" << ENDL << "┃╰━╯┣━┳━━┳╮╱╭┳━━┳━┻╮╭╋━━╮╰╯╭╯┃" << ENDL << "┃╭━━┫╭┫╭╮┃┃╱┃┃┃━┫╭━┫┃┃╭╮┃╭╮╰╮┃" << ENDL << "┃┃╱╱┃┃┃╰╯┃╰━╯┃┃━┫╰━┫╰┫╰╯┃┃╰━╯┃" << ENDL << "╰╯╱╱╰╯╰━━┻━╮╭┻━━┻━━┻━┻━━╯╰━━━╯" << ENDL << "╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭━╯┃" << ENDL << "╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╰━━╯" << ENDL << ENDL;
        cout << "█▀▀ █▀█ ▄▀█ █▀▀ █ ▄▀█ █▀   █▀█ █▀█ █▀█   ░░█ █░█ █▀▀ ▄▀█ █▀█" << ENDL << "█▄█ █▀▄ █▀█ █▄▄ █ █▀█ ▄█   █▀▀ █▄█ █▀▄   █▄█ █▄█ █▄█ █▀█ █▀▄" << ENDL;
        break;

      default:
        cout << "índice u opción inválido." << ENDL;
        break;
    }
  } while (seleccionado != 5);
  return;
}

int main(){ _
  // freopen("file.in","r",stdin);
  // freopen("file.out","w",stdout);
  cout << "╭━━━╮╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭╮╱╱╱╱╭━━━╮" << ENDL << "┃╭━╮┃╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭╯╰╮╱╱╱┃╭━╮┃" << ENDL << "┃╰━╯┣━┳━━┳╮╱╭┳━━┳━┻╮╭╋━━╮╰╯╭╯┃" << ENDL << "┃╭━━┫╭┫╭╮┃┃╱┃┃┃━┫╭━┫┃┃╭╮┃╭╮╰╮┃" << ENDL << "┃┃╱╱┃┃┃╰╯┃╰━╯┃┃━┫╰━┫╰┫╰╯┃┃╰━╯┃" << ENDL << "╰╯╱╱╰╯╰━━┻━╮╭┻━━┻━━┻━┻━━╯╰━━━╯" << ENDL << "╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╭━╯┃" << ENDL << "╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╱╰━━╯" << ENDL << ENDL << ENDL << "█▀█ █▀█ █▀█   ▄▀█ █░░ █▀▀ ▀▄▀ █▀█ ▀▄▀ █▀█" << ENDL << "█▀▀ █▄█ █▀▄   █▀█ █▄▄ ██▄ █░█ █▄█ █░█ █▄█" << ENDL << ENDL;
  cout << "Presiona enter para continuar: ";
  string desechable;
  getline(cin, desechable);
  menu_principal();
  return 0;
}
```

Los blogs que estuve viendo fueron estos (No se si sea relevante):
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch
https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/cpp/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-cpp/
[¿Como modificar un archivo .txt desde c++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21171/como-modificar-un-archivo-txt-desde-c)

Comment: ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, revisa [help] y [ask]. En concreto, la pregunta necesita más detalle; por favor edítala para añadir qué error te sale y en qué línea.

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta con el mensaje de terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `menu_principal` está definida después que la función `menu_jugar`, por eso en el momento de que la invocas desde la función `menu_jugar` el compilador aún no la conoce.

Antes de definir la función `menu_principal`, incluye una línea con la siguiente declaración:

```
void menu_principal();
```

De esta forma cuando el compilador llegue a la llamada ya conocerá la forma en que debe invocar esta función.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió mucho.